# anyway of avoiding duplicate code in the if-else branch

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

Here is the table and data

```
CREATE TABLE #Customers
(
    ID              INT NOT NULL,
    ProductID       INT NOT NULL,
    OrderID         INT NULL
)

INSERT INTO #Customers VALUES (1,10,1)
INSERT INTO #Customers VALUES (2,10,NULL)
INSERT INTO #Customers VALUES (3,10,5)
INSERT INTO #Customers VALUES (4,20,NULL)
INSERT INTO #Customers VALUES (5,20,NULL)
INSERT INTO #Customers VALUES (6,20,22)
GO
```

I have a a stored procedure where decision of result is based on a parameter @OrderID. If @OrderID is not null then it returns rows matching this param otherwise return all rows. Something like as follows.

```
DECLARE @OrderID INT 
SET @OrderID = NULL

IF @OrderID IS NULL 
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM #Customers
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM #Customers
    WHERE OrderID = @OrderID 
END
```

I was just wondering if there is anyway of writing a WHERE clause that can cover both cases. This way I can avoid duplication of code in the IF-ELSE branch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can write it as

```
        SELECT * FROM #Customers
WHERE (OrderID = @OrderID  or @OrderID is Null)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @OrderId INT = NULL

SELECT * 
FROM #Customers c
WHERE 1=1
AND (@OrderId IS NULL OR c.OrderId = @OrderId)
```

If variable @ORderId is NULL all rows will return. If it is not NULL then the second half of the filter will fire.

Comment: 1=1 seem unnecessary here. Any particular reason for using this

Comment: I do it out of habit so that I can change the where filters more easily when I am desinging my queries. It is totally optional and doesn't affect anything to keep it in or out (other than my sanity).